# MULE expression-transformer not accepted

Tags: mule, expression

I'm trying to learn Mule ESB but get problems with example projects. Why are these lines
underlined red and not represented in the Message flow?

```
<expression-transformer name="returnAttachments">
        <return-argument evaluator="attachments-list" expression="*.txt,*.ozb,*.xml" optional="false"/>
    </expression-transformer>
```

I've cut and pasted these lines from mulesoft.org as part of a sample project.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

@genjosanzo is right, the MEL equivalent would be:

```
<expression-transformer
        expression="#[($.value in message.inboundAttachments.entrySet() if $.key ~= '(.*\\.txt|.*\\.ozb|.*\\.xml)')]" />
```

Answer (score 1):

Mule studio has problem rendering nested elements (bug reported [here](http://www.mulesoft.org/jira/browse/STUDIO-2295))

Instead you can use the compact version and replace it with the following:

```
<expression-transformer expression="#[attachments-list:*.txt,*.ozb,*.xml]"  doc:name="Expression" />
```

On a side note ever since mule 3.3.0 the new [mule expression languages](http://www.mulesoft.org/documentation/display/MULE3USER/Mule+Expression+Language) and it is recommended to rely on it whenever possible.

Comment: You need to accept @genjosanzo's answer otherwise the question remains open.