# No payload when receiving rich text or HTML mails with MULE

Tags: imap, mule

I'm trying to develop a Mule application with inbound IMAP connector. It works fine when the incoming mail is plain text but when it's HTML or Rich Text there's no text in the payload. How to make the application independent of the incoming mail type?

Comment: Since you're new to StackOverflow, let me explain that it is good practice to accept answers or if not comment why you reject them. For example, you haven't done anything here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13931716/mule-expression-transformer-not-accepted

Answer (score 1, accepted):

HTML or Rich Text are most probably MIME multipart emails. In that case, Mule tries to extract the text has payload only if the multipart email contains a first part that is has a content type starting with `text/` (like `text/plain`). I reckon that in your case, the multipart email doesn't match this rule, thus Mule doesn't know what to do with it.

I suggest you use a choice router to deal with the case when there's no text in the payload after the email has been received. In that case, use whatever logic that is relevant to you to extract the content from one of the inbound attachments into which the different parts have been transferred.

Comment: Thank you very much! I've come a bit further now beeing able to convert the different parts of the message into plain text with a JAVA-application. Now I'll try to get this working together with the Mule-flow.

Answer (score 0):

I've been able to write some Java-code that bring out the text-part of a multipart message but I can't find a way to get this working with Mule. MUle wants to load the class with a String even though it's a multi part message.

The code I've written is below:

```
import javax.activation.DataHandler;
import javax.mail.*;
public class ReadMultipartMail3 {

public String stringback(Part payload) throws Exception {
  String answer ="";

 if(payload.isMimeType("text/plain") || payload.isMimeType("text/html"))
  { 
  answer=(payload.getContent().toString());
}
     else{
 Multipart multipart = (Multipart) payload.getContent();


for (int x = 0; x < multipart.getCount(); x++) {
  Part p = multipart.getBodyPart(x);
  System.out.println("Content Type:     "+p.getContentType());
  BodyPart bodyPart = multipart.getBodyPart(x);

String disposition = bodyPart.getDisposition();

if (disposition != null && (disposition.equals(BodyPart.ATTACHMENT))) {
 System.out.println("Mail have some attachment : ");

 DataHandler handler = bodyPart.getDataHandler();
 System.out.println("file name : " + handler.getName());
 } else {

  if(p.isMimeType("text/plain") || p.isMimeType("text/html"))
  { 
  answer = (p.getContent().toString());
  }
  else if (p.isMimeType("multipart/alternative")) 
  { 
  Multipart mp = (Multipart)p.getContent(); 
  int partsCount = mp.getCount();
  for (int z = 0; z < partsCount; z++) {
      System.out.println("Content Type:     "+z+"  "+mp.getBodyPart(z).getContentType());
      if(mp.getBodyPart(z).getContentType().contains("text/plain"))
              {answer = (String) mp.getBodyPart(z).getContent();}

  }  
}

}

 }
  }
  return answer;}}
```

Comment: Case closed, the solution was to check the Disable Transport Transformation checkbox in the IMAP inbound connector.